# Decoding manchester code without the clock input

Tags: decoding

[image: Manchester code]

I'm trying to decipher messages from my smokedetectors to be able to get them connected to the  system that controls the rest of the house. I've tried to decode the message myself, but from what I expected to find I cannot seem make out the different parts of information in the code.

I think I've found the bit that indicates an alarm from the smoke detector. But on the radio there is a number, which is also part of the serial number, so I expected to find this number in the transmission, but I've tried all combinations but cannot find a match. Not sure if this is even in there, but I would expect it to be used as an address for the smoke detector.

Is there some experts in this that could help me translate this the attached bit-stream just so I can check if I'm even on the right track on the decoding.

The clock signal is not available. But based on articles I've found on this subject online I'm assuming the clock-period is the same as one "long" pulse on the picture.

Comment: Looks like this question has been flagged for being off topic - which is fair. I think it would potentially get more interest on the electrical engineering site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Manchester signalling defines a T2 period as a clock cycle. Ultimately 1 divided by the time period for your high pulse width on the "long" pulses is the bit rate used by the ICs communicating with each other.

Single ended Manchester signalling encodes bit values as voltage level transitions at the midpoint (T1) of a T2 period. The direction of the transition is actually defined by what Manchester encoding is being used. There are two types Manchester II or IEEE standard. See diagram below

[image]